# OpenERP record Salary

Tags: openerp

I'm trying to know how to use open erp using OpenERP online demo, so far it's ok except i'm failing to understand how to record salary for an employee though there exist several employees in the system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you might need to install the `hr_payroll` module. Look through the different [HR modules](http://apps.openerp.com/?filter=%7B%22order_by%22:%20%22click_counter%20desc%22,%20%22text_search%22:%20%22payroll%22%7D&text_search=hr) to see if there's one that contains what you need.

Comment: I'm seeing that it is currently under development here, http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/features/payroll.html